# Send a Blob From Navision to a Javascript Add In

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I have a Blob Object in NAV, which represents an Excel document. I want this document to be displayed in my JavaScript Control AddIn (run in Web- and Windows-Client). But I am not sure how to handle this problem. Later in the AddIn, I need the Blob as a binary string.

So far I tried two things.

**First try**

I build an interface with this method

```
[ApplicationVisible]
void SetExcelDocument(ExcelDocument ExcelDocument);
```

and the `ExcelDocument` - Object looks like this

```
[Serializable]
public class ExcelDocument
{
    //Constructor
    public ExcelDocument()
    {
        CurrentExcelDocument = null;
    }

    //store Blob
    public Stream CurrentExcelDocument { get; set; }

}
```

So in NAV, i convert the Blob in a .Net MemoryStream variable, which looks like this

```
MemStream DotNet System.IO.System.IO.MemoryStream.'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

and the code like this

```
TechnicalSpreadsheet.CALCFIELDS(Document);             //Get Blob (Document is table column name)
TechnicalSpreadsheet.Document.CREATEINSTREAM(Lstr_BlobInstream);

MemStream := MemStream.MemoryStream();
COPYSTREAM(MemStream,Lstr_BlobInstream);
ExcelDocument := ExcelDocument.ExcelDocument;          //Initialize Object
ExcelDocument.CurrentExcelDocument := MemStream;       //set MemoryStream

CurrPage.spreadsheet.SetExcelDocument(ExcelDocument);  //Call function in AddIn
```

The code is executed, when the AddIn is ready. the Nav variable `ExcelDocument` is defined as this

```
ExcelDocument DotNet <Reference to Object here>, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d02dbb9bbac93844'
```

So the problem here is, I can only set an instance of `ExcelDocument` in NAV, when the property "RunOnClient" is set to yes. But this is not working for the WebClient ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh168747(v=nav.90).aspx)). But however even setting the property to yes, won`t send the data to the AddIn.

**Second Try**

For the second try, I changed the datatype. So I used a `byte[]` instead of a stream. So ich changed the interface to this

```
[ApplicationVisible]
void SetExcelDocument(byte[] ExcelDocument);
```

and just changed the AddIn function call in NAV to this

```
CurrPage.spreadsheet.SetExcelDocument(MemStream.ToArray);  //Call function in AddIn
```

and removed the `ExcelDocument` variable.

This works but the data does not look like binary data. I would expect some unreadable stuff when displaying it in the web console, but I get readable letters and numbers instead. And I am not sure how to convert this to a binary string.

There is some nice [input](http://vjeko.com/passing-strongly-typed-data-javascript-control-add/) from Vjeko, but this does not work for me either.

Comment: What you gonna do with this sheet in add-in? I mean what you are going to feed it to?

Comment: And yeh basicaly binary (byte) string is just letters and nubmers as it is characters from 0 to 256.

Comment: I only want to display it in the AddIn. Maybe do some changes, but i did not talk about this with my colleagues, because it is not required yet. It was a .Net AddIn where everything works fine, but .Net AddIn do not work in WebClient, so I decided to do a JavaScript AddIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to send the blob to JavaScript Control AddIn. Here is what i did.

In the interface of the control AddIn I defined the method

```
[ApplicationVisible]
void SetExcelDocument(ExcelDocument exceldoc);
```

where the `ExcelDocument` - Object looks like this

```
[Serializable]
public class ExcelDocument
{
    public string ExcelJson;  //Excel Content stored in JSON format

    public byte[] Excel
    {
        get
        {
            return null;      //Not needed in the AddIn
        }
        set
        {
            IConverter converter = new Converter();
            ExcelJson = converter.ArrayBufferOfExcelDocToJson(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The magic is now happening in the new `Converter` - class. Shortly I convert the byte array to a Stream, then read the Stream (respectively the Excel document) with the help of [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and finally convert the content of the document with Newtonsoft.JSON to a Json string (variable `ExcelJson`).

In NAV it will look like this.

```
//Get Blob (Document is table column name)
TechnicalSpreadsheet.Document.CREATEINSTREAM(Lstr_BlobInstream);  
//init Memory Stream 
MemStream := MemStream.MemoryStream();              
COPYSTREAM(MemStream,Lstr_BlobInstream);
//Init DotNet Variable 
ExcelDocument := ExcelDocument.ExcelDocument;
//Set byte[]
ExcelDocument.Excel := MemStream.GetBuffer;
//Call function in AddIn
CurrPage.spreadsheet.SetExcelDocument(ExcelDocument);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this piece of code to add binary node to XML file. By this I was able to send file as binary data to web service. Try play with it maybe it will  help. It uses ActiveX because it was written for Nav 5. You can replace it with .net.

```
  pNodeName@1210000 : Text[50];VAR pXMLDoc@1210001 : Automation "{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221} 6.0:{88D96A05-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}:'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.DOMDocument60";pPath@1210002 : Text[1024]);
  Att@1210009 : Automation "{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221} 6.0:{2933BF86-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}:'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMElement";
  parent@1210008 : Automation "{F5078F18-C551-11D3-89B9-0000F81FE221} 6.0:{2933BF86-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}:'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMElement";
  AdoStream@1210003 : Automation "{B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129} 6.1:{00000566-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}:'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library'.Stream";

  Att := pXMLDoc.createElement(pNodeName);
  CREATE(AdoStream, TRUE);
  AdoStream.Type := 1; //Binary
  AdoStream.Open();
  AdoStream.LoadFromFile(pPath);
  Att.dataType('bin.hex');
  Att.nodeTypedValue := AdoStream.Read;
  AdoStream.Close();
  parent := pXMLDoc.documentElement;
  parent.appendChild(Att);
```